# CSS3 :not selector in IE7/8 when page includes partial vb.net postback

Tags: css, selectivizr

I have the following CSS which is working fine in all browsers except any less that IE9.

```
table:not([class]) {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}
```

I have a *selectivizr* javascript pack which does a pretty good job of fixing this, until a partial postback is made to the page... then it all gets totally ignored because it is not in the pageLoad function.

Can anyone think of another way around this?

I have used the :not selector to avoid all other tables inheriting these styles.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with selectivizr though I think it is something they plan on doing. I read somewhere of someone including the script again each time dynamic content was added but this is not recommended practice. Are you already using jQuery? In that case you are better off using jQuery. If you are concerned about the size of jquery maybe try [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) or directly use jquery's [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) engine.